# Postfix: restrict outgoing mail sender domains

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix 3.2.4, listening on port 25 for both incoming and outgoing mail. I know, it would be much better to use 587 submission port, but I can't reconfigure all of the existing email clients already using port 25. Clients use SASL authentication.

In order to avoid misconfiguration and/or misuse, I would like to only allow outgoing mail if it comes from an allowed domain, i.e. the sender address (the FROM mail header) belongs to one of my domains.

I know it could be easily done using a separate sumbission port for outgoing email, but is there any way to do it using the same 25 port for both icoming and outgoing email?

Thanks!